# Combining data frames in R

Tags: r

I have several data frames with the same columns and I would like to combine them in such a way that identifies which data frame they are from. For example, if in data frame #1, I have this data:

```
  x y
1 a 1
2 b 4
```

And in data frame #2, I have this data:

```
  x y
1 d 6
2 e 7
```

I would like to combine them into one data frame with a new column that identifies which data frame they came from:

```
  frame x y
1     1 a 1
2     1 b 4
3     2 d 6
4     2 e 7
```

The frame column identifies that rows 1 and 2 are from data frame #1, and rows 3 and 4 are from data frame #2. I'm using strings to identify my data frames, but I just used numbers here to make the example simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data frames are sitting in a list, following should work:

```
dfList <- list(
  df1 = data.frame(x=letters[1:2],y=1:2),
  df2 = data.frame(x=letters[3:4],y=3:4)
  )

newDF <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:length(dfList)) {
  newDF <- rbind(newDF, cbind(frame=rep(i,length(dfList[[i]])),dfList[[i]]))
}
newDF
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the same list approach as @Shambho with `do.call`:

```
dfList <- list(
    df1 = data.frame(x=letters[1:2],y=1:2),
    df2 = data.frame(x=letters[3:4],y=3:4)
)


data.frame(
    frame = rep(seq_along(dfList), sapply(dfList, nrow)),
    do.call(rbind, dfList), row.names=NULL
)

##   frame x y
## 1     1 a 1
## 2     1 b 2
## 3     2 c 3
## 4     2 d 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Or like this?:

Assuming `df1` and `df2` are your data frame 1 and 2, respectively:

```
data.frame(frame=rep(1:2,lapply(list(df1,df2),function(x) dim(x)[1])),rbind(df1,df2))
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished pretty simply with `cbind` and `rbind`:

```
rbind(cbind(frame=1, dat1), cbind(frame=2, dat2))
#    frame x y
# 1      1 a 1
# 2      1 b 4
# 11     2 d 6
# 21     2 e 7
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple datasets named as `df1`, `df2`, etc.

```
library(plyr)
library(stringr)
Names <-ls(pattern="df")
ldply(setNames(mget(Names),str_extract(Names,"\\d+")))
 # .id x y
#1   1 a 1
#2   1 b 4
#3   2 d 6
#4   2 e 7
```